# Symfony Doctrine query entries by datetime and timezone

Tags: mysql, datetime, symfony, doctrine, timezone

I've got an webservice written with Symfony. An app calls to it and enters messages which have to be send to the app at a specific time. A cronjob on the server runs every minute and checks which messages have to be send. But the user can define a time frame when he whants to receive those messages.

I query those messages the following way:

```
$query = $em->createQuery('
    SELECT m
    FROM MyBundle:Message m
    INNER JOIN m.user u
    WHERE m.active = true
        AND m.nextMessageOn <= :now
        AND u.receiveMessagesFrom <= :now
        AND u.receiveMessagesTo >= :now
    ORDER BY m.id ASC
')->setParameter('now', new \DateTime('now'));
```

*(For presentation purpose the "from time" has to be before the "to time")*

Now I've got the problem, that the **user can have a different timezone than the server.**

Is there some kind of best practice how to handle the hole time (datetime) / timezone / server / app problem? And especially for Symfony (Doctrine) is there a clean way to query those items?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should save the correct timezone for the user in the database and read this: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/cookbook/working-with-datetime.html

Comment: Ok, I hoped I could save the timezone with the date, but that approach is also good. What I don't get: How can I use/integrate the custom DateTimeType?

Comment: Ok, you need to add the type to the config.yml like mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10955563/storing-doctrine2-datetime-in-utc-only Unfortunately there are two problems. As I don't want to have it in the platform timezone, but the individual user ones, I need to add an converter for the display anyway. And I use a column "updatedOn" with type="datetime" and "@ORM\Version". It will save me the current time when an entity is updated. Unfortunately this is still saved in the platform timezone. So that's a little bit confusing.

Comment: Also the timezone conversion will just be triggered when the entity is first flushed to the database. It might be better to build a converter class and call it's methods within the setter and getter of date time properties.

Comment: That's correct, the timezone is set if you flush the entity. If you already have data in your database your have to manually correct this. Symfony2 is MVC so don't convert your timezones at the model level, do this in your controllers. Here is an example how you get the timezone out of the database if a user logged in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10694315/symfony2-where-to-set-a-user-defined-time-zone. More info about timezones and symfony2: https://matt.drollette.com/2012/07/user-specific-timezones-with-symfony2-and-twig-extensions/